# Reopen request for "how to order food that is hot temperature but not hot amount-of-capsaicin"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How to order food that is hot (temperature) but not hot (amount of capsaicin)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182481/how-to-order-food-that-is-hot-temperature-but-not-hot-amount-of-capsaicin)

The author has edited the question.

Comment: The author needs to radically edit that question for it to be reopened. The title and initial paragraph ask for hot spicy (translation of 'scharf'). But then his last addendum asks for foods with capsicum. Spicy includes that, but he wants something more specific. He needs to change the title and limit the question to about capsicum. (and the answer is that there is no single word for it.)

Comment: @Mitch `So in a restaurant I want to order food that contains no capsaicin.` That's part of the original. The title has always clearly stated that he means `amount of capsaicin`. It's irrelevant what the German text says, this is EL&U not DL&U. I was under the impression FumbleFingers closed it by accident due to his new superpowers and meant to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: OK. Yes. Now it's clear to me. He did have all that information in his question all along. He has been asking all along for a word in English that means 'contains capsicum'. So 1) there is none (so any discussion requires more words and explanation, in real life and in ELU) and 'Please no capsicum containing ingredients' will need explanation anyway 2) The wording of his question is so heavily ingrained with the temperature/spiciness distinction that it is very hard to see that it is not a duplicate. 3) Your answer is enough. There is no more to be said by reopening. You can still edit though.

Comment: @Mitch My point isn't really to have it reopened for further discussion, it's just that it isn't a duplicate. I'm not bothered if it's closed as too localised or off-topic or any other close reason (that makes sense). It is not a duplicate of the other question, this is about avoiding the irritant capsaicin, not the fruit capsicum nor really the confusion between hot & spicy (it was that confusion that caused the author to ask for a clearer term). I don't suppose many people will (or indeed should) come here for advice on capsaicin in the future, so I guess it doesn't matter much really.

Comment: Bear in mind that "duplicate" doesn't mean "exact duplicate"; it means that an answer on another question answers this one. In this case, the answers say that there is no word differentiating between hot-spicy and hot-hot. That may be a sufficient answer for this question too.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's not even close, never mind exact. The author did point out that the other question/answer did not answer his question. Maybe the author's question is too technical/scientific for this site; just an hour ago someone linked (in a comment) to yet another question about hot vs spicy when this question is about capsaicin (not capsicums, not hot and not spicy). Anyways, I shouldn't have bothered: wasn't my question and I don't suppose I actually care if things are marked wrongly but the fact that the author made an effort to edit it (twice) made me feel I should bring it up.

Comment: @Frank: It wasn't an "accidental" closure on my part, and I don't see the subsequent edits change anything much. The OP is now wriggling on a pin claiming he wants to distinguish ***capsaicin*** "heat" from that caused by ***allyl isothiocyanate** (mustard, radishes, horseradish, wasabi), **gingerol/shogaol** (ginger), **piperine** (black pepper), **syn-Propanethial-S-oxide** (onions), etc., etc. But the question title itself belies this ridiculously fine distinction, since it presupposes we're talking at the level where *hot = high temperature* could be relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No problem, I did think you'd maybe put your pants on on the outside of your trousers for a minute and hit the duplicate button without realising you were using the force. I'm still not convinced it's a duplicate but as the Americans like to say 'I could care less', which I could but it doesn't seem worth it. No sweat (unlike the capsaicin intolerant author) :)

Comment: @Frank: I won't deny that if the text of the second question had included the subsequent amendments it's at least *feasible* I might not have closevoted. I might have simply commented to point out the mismatch between the title and the text, and to say it seems almost inconceivable that English would have a standard way of distinguishing *capsaicin* from several other types of "spicy heat", given the fact that we habitually use *hot, burning, scorching*, etc., for both taste and *temperature*. Then "comment-linked" the original and left it to others to closevote (I imagine they *would* have).